# Benefiting from channukah candles in a mirror

Tags: halacha, chanuka, see-sight-vision-blind, menora-chanukia, hanaah-benefit

One is not allowed to "benefit" from the lights of the channukah candles. Rashi says the reason is in order that it should be recognizable that these candles are light for the mitzvah in order to "l'farsem hanas" (to promote the miracle.) The Ran says the reason is because that these lights are similar to that of the Menorah (in the Beis Mikdash) that one is not allowed to have benefit from, so to the channukah candles.

Would this din also apply if one is benefiting from the light that is reflected in a mirror?

The reason why I am asking and think that it might not be a problem according to Rashi is because one doesn't necessarily see that you are benefiting from the "actual" candles, and therefore, according to Rashi, it's still recognizable that these candles are for the mitzvah. Perhaps, according to the Ran, it's more of a problem since one is still benefiting from the light. However, maybe it's only the "direct" light that would be a problem according to the Ran.

Comment: I thought we weren't allowed to benefit from *them*. Meaning you couldn't roast a marshmallow on your candles either.

Comment: Would the light emitting from the mirror exist if the candles weren't lit?

Comment: I seem to recall that a person can only give eidus on something that they see directly, but not if they saw it happening via a reflection. Perhaps there is some connection to this case.

Comment: Are you asking according to Rashi, Ran, or other (eg., Shulhan 'Aruch)?

Answer (score 1):

Yalkut Yosef English Hanukkah (S673.29)

"Although it is forbidden to use the light of the Hanukkah lamps it's permissible to see by their light.  Therefore, if the electric lights have been extinguished...and the only light comes from Hanukkah lamps, it is permissible to walk through the house although one is aided by that light.  It is not necessary to shut one's eyes to avoid benefitting from their light."
The note specifies that this type of usage is not considered using "their" light.  See more in Hazon Ovadya pg 100.